# How can I fix my Dell laptop's wireless connection?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, laptop

I've just installed Ubuntu on my Dell laptop, and the wireless is not working.

How could I fix it ? Is there any driver I should install?

Note: I'm also running windows 7 on the same laptop and the wireless connection works just fine.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks!

> **EDIT : Wifi card model description :** vendor : broadcom corporation product : BCM4312 802.11b/g LP -PHY version  : 01 configuration :
>   driver = b43 -pci-bridge latency=0

Comment: Which Ubuntu version , which WiFi card model ? Is your wireless card detected by the system ?

Comment: Ubuntu version is 12.10 , how could I check what is the Wifi card model and whether it's detected by the system or not ? Thanks !

Comment: ifconfig, iwconfig, lsusb, lspci - run each command via sudo and paste us the output

Comment: "sudo rfkill -list all" might also help.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: Not working as in? Not connecting? or low speeds? please be specific

Answer (score 0):

follow the below link
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Here go to the section b43: No internet access
follow the steps in this section. 
Note: b43 fwcutter is a must so without step 1 do not proceed to further steps.

Once done with all 4 steps goto the section switching between drivers:
Herein remove (if existing) drivers. It might happen that some driver will not be there.
for my case: after doing sudo modprobe -r wl
I got error: FATAL: wl not loaded. So not to worry
Then do loading them, by following the commands.

Once you are done please check:
1) sudo rfkill list all
if it shows as below:
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

Hard blocked yes means there is hardware switch on your computer/laptop which has disabled the wifi.
With this : Hardware swicth blocked can be seen under wireless icon.
Now to turn it on read below:
for my case: dell inspiron 1525, press Fn+Alt+F2 to turn on the wifi.

Thanks